# From an (ID, number) pair keep only those pairs that contain the largest number

Tags: python, regex

I am new in python and I would like some help for a small problem. I have a file whose each line has an ID plus an associated number. More than one numbers can be associated to the same ID. How is it possible to get only the ID plus the largest number associated with it in python?

Example:

Input: ID_file.txt

ENSG00000133246 2013  
                                                         ENSG00000133246 540
ENSG00000133246 2010
ENSG00000253626 465
ENSG00000211829 464
ENSG00000158458 2577
ENSG00000158458 2553

What I want is the following:

ENSG00000133246 2013
ENSG00000253626 465
ENSG00000211829 464
ENSG00000158458 2577

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you need to preserve order like your sample output shows? Also, are runs of the same ID always contiguous as in your sample input? Also, why did you put the "regex" tag here?

Comment: If, like abarnert asked, runs of the same ID are always contiguous, I would use http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby + max()

Comment: @Bwmat: That's exactly what I was getting at.

Comment: I would like to observe that if you do make that assumption then you have more trouble if your input is ever not in the order you expect.  You would never know if there is a problem.  These look like polling values from a sensor or genetic data.  If it is genetic data then it should be in order but if it is not genetic data then you need to expect a more general expression.

Comment: @PyNEwbie: That's exactly why I asked the OP, and made sure to point out the assumption in my answer, rather than just silently assuming it. It's also quite possible that the order matters, in which case your `dict` solution will give the wrong answer, which is why I asked the OP about that also. When you have an underspecified question, it's always best to point out all the assumptions and ask for them to be verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think there are many ways to do this I would though use a dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict

id_value_dict = defaultdict()
for line in open(idfile.txt).readlines():
    id, value = line.strip().split()
    if id not in id_value_dict:
        id_value_dict[id] = int(value)
    else:
        if id_value_dict[id] < int(value):
            id_value_dict[id] = int(value)
```

Next step is to get the dictionary written out

```
out_ref = open(outputfile.txt,'w')
for key, value in id_value_dict:
    outref.write(key + '\t' + str(value)

outref.close()
```

There are slicker ways to do this, I think the dictionary could be written in a one-liner using a lamda or a list-comprehension but I like to start simple

Just in case you need the results sorted there are lots of ways to do it but I think it is critical to understand working with lists and dictionaries in python as I have found that the learning to think about the right data container is usually the key to solving many of my problems but I am still a new.  Any way if you need the sorted results a straightforward was is to

```
 id_value_dict.keys().sort()
```

SO this is one of the slick things about python id_value__dict.keys() is a list of the keys of the dictionary sorted

```
 out_ref = open(outputfile.txt,'w')
 for key in id_value_dict.keys():
     outref.write(key + '\t' + str(id_value_dict[key])

 outref.close()
```

its really tricky because you might want (I know I always want) to code

```
  my_sorted_list = id_value_dict.keys().sort()
```

However you will find that my_sorted_list does not exist (NoneType)

Comment: Why are you using a `defaultdict` but then checking `id not in id_value_dict` anyway? Just do one or the other.

Comment: Also, why are you using `readlines` instead of just iterating the file?

Comment: Read my handle I keep it simple so I can understand exactly what I am doing.

Comment: But adding things like an unnecessary `readlines` or a `defaultdict` when a plain `dict` would do makes it more complicated, not simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your very valuable observation

Comment: Thanks for the solution PyNewbie! However, because I wanted to preserve the order of the items present in the idfile.txt, instead of defaultdict() I used the OrderedDict().

Answer (score 1):

Given that your input consists of nothing but contiguous runs for each ID—that is, as soon as you see another ID, you never see the previous ID again—you can just do this:

```
import itertools
import operator

with open('ID_file.txt') as idfile, open('max_ID_file.txt', 'w') as maxidfile:
    keyvalpairs = (line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in idfile)
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(keyvalpairs, operator.itemgetter(0)):
        maxval = max(int(keyval[1]) for keyval in group)
        maxidfile.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, maxval))
```

To see what this does, let's go over it line by line.

A file is just an iterable full of lines, so `for line in idfile` means exactly what you'd expect. For each line, we're calling `strip` to get rid of extraneous whitespace, then `split(None, 1)` to split it on the first space, so we end up with an iterable full of pairs of strings.

Next, we use [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to change that into an iterable full of (key, group) pairs. Try printing out `list(keyvalpairs)` to see what it looks like.

Then we iterate over that, and just use `max` to get the largest value in each group.

And finally, we print out the key and the max value for the group.

Comment: +1.  I had written up a solution that did approximately the same thing with list comprehensions, but using `itertools` is cleaner.

Comment: Perfect! A very neat solution indeed! Thanks abarnert and the rest of the people for their responses